# Does (아/어)야 always mean 'have to/must', or does it have other meanings when used as a conjunction?

Tags: grammar

Most Korean learners will learn the **아/어야 하다/되다/지/겠다** family of constructions fairly early on. Usually these end a phrase and simply mean that something must or should be done:

> 저는 밥을 먹어야 해요 -  I have to eat 
>   대학교에 가고 싶다면 열심히 공부해야 돼요 - If you want to go to University, you must study hard 
>   무엇을 사 드릴까 결정해야갰어요 - We’ll have to decide what we’re going to get for him

Where I get confused is with 'conjunctive' uses of 야, which make me wonder what '야' means in general.

This instance seems easy enough to understand:

> 먹어야 삽니다 - to live, you must eat.

We can still see that what's on the left side of 야 (먹다) is something that should be done, so this is similar to the non-conjunctive examples above.

However, in cases like:

> 바보가 아니고야 왜 그 말도 모르니? - how do you not know that word unless you’re an
>   idiot?
>
> 뛰어 봐야 이미 늦은걸요 - you can run around all you like; it’s too late now.

It's hard to see how '야' has the meaning of 'must'. Is there any way to rearrange those English translations so that I can see that '야' has a meaning of 'must'? Or does it actually mean something different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to see *only if* in the first type of use and *even if* in the second, as follows.

> 먹어야 삽니다
>   Only if you ate, could you live.
>
> 해야 한다.
>   It would be OK only if you did.

*Only if* of course can be related to a *must*.  IF only if A then B, THEN whoever wants B *must* A.

As for the second type,

> 뛰어 봐야 늦었다
>   Even if we ran, we'd be late.

The scheme does not give you exactly what you wanted, i.e. a reduction of the usages to *must*, but one to *if*.

One of the examples does not appear to accommodate either *only if* or *even if* that well, but just a plain *if* seems to work:

> 바보가 아니고야 왜 그 말도 모르니?
>   If you are not a fool, why don't you know what that means?

Compare the sense of *if* in something like, 'The advice was good if unsolicited.' There it means something like *although.* What I am trying to suggest is that these critical connecting words can have subtly different senses in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The second definition of -어야:

> 2. (뒤에 오는 부정어와 함께 쓰여) 아무리 가정하여도 영향이 없음을 나타내는 연결 어미.
>
>    - 네가 아무리 울어야 소용이 없다. *It doesn't matter how much you cry.*

In the construction "A어야 B", if the following phrase B is a negative one, like 없다, 모르다, etc, it indicates that no matter how much you suppose A, B is always going to happen.

-고야 is probably -고 나서야 for short.